# How to avoid to give written "Peer Feedback" to a senior colleague who I believe is sabotaging me

Tags: communication, germany, feedback

*Note: I am Junior to this guy, and he has the power to decide over my future in the company at least partly. This takes place in Germany.*

The company I am working at encourages peer reviews which are made on online forms. These are only between the one giving feedback, and the one receiving it. They are not shared with anyone else. Also these are **completely optional**.

The Senior in question asked me several times via mail, chat and in person to fill out this form. I really don't want to. I don't have much nice to say, and this form is extremely long. It takes more than 15 minutes to fill out and I really don't feel like lying. 
If I am honest I fear it hurts my future with the company.

**Question: How can I dodge this task, without him being mad at me. And without him noticing that it would have been bad feedback.**

*(I literally just told him I will "think about it")*

(EDIT: I already did 9 forms for other colleagues, but even if I had all the time in the world I would not want to fill out this form for him)

(EDIT 2: I will write one specific example: Our boss told me to do something, like "Do this and show your personal skillset like x, y and z!" afterwards he (the senior in question) comes up to me as says "No do a, b and c, I know you can do x, y and z you don't have to prove it" If I tell him our boss said I should do x, y and z, he tells me "That is not open for discussion I know better what our boss wants from you!" ... **I did not want to include this context in the beginning because it is very specific, and I wanted the question to be helpful for others as well**)

(EDIT 3: Topic sabotaging: You need to trust me on this one, I could probably write an entire book about situations like this. I asked a different boss I get along with really well (he is for another team) and even he told be to be extra careful with this senior. The space in our company is limited, and if I as a junior can't keep up the the standards they have for seniors, I will be replaced by a senior sooner or later)

Comment: 15 min is not long to fill, that's a quite short form. Also, can't you find (true) good things to say about your colleague if you are afraid of repercussions?

Comment: As a first idea, have you tried to ask him _why_ he wants _you_ to fill it? Could you please clarify how long you have been working in this company/with this guy?

Comment: @Captain Emacs 15min for each colleagues adds up. I work with 40 other devs here. That would be more than 1 workday to write a review for everyone. I could find some good things. But the form asks question like: "Give an example of the leadership quality of this person which you personally noticed".

Comment: @Pudora Your question states only towards your senior in question

Comment: @ebosi I have been working 2,5 years at this company. This guy has worked 1 year at this company. He wants me to fill it because we do work together quite a lot. And he is not in any team. (Usually devs only ask their close team members for feedback)

Comment: @Twyxz I am sorry I don't understand your comment. (English is not my mother tounge)

Comment: @Pudora It appeared that you are required to give feedback only about this person, not about everybody in the company (which does not make sense, anyway). In any case, if I do not know a person, or their work, I say, I am unable to give informed feedback.

Comment: How many reviews are you expected to write?  1 or 40?

Comment: @Snow I am expected to write for my team (8devs) the senior in question is not part of my team.

Comment: Can you please make this clear in your question.  Your question currently implies that you're writing one review (for your senior) and then in comments, you raise 40.  Please indicate how many reviews you need to write for and for whom.

Comment: @Brandin I already wrote a review for someone outside my team

Comment: Changing the title to include the word sabotage changes the tone of this question significantly. Why do you think they are trying to sabotage you?

Comment: @SaggingRufus I added an example of his "bad" behavior towards me, and because motosubatsu told me it changes the answers I thought I would include it also in the title

Comment: @Pudora that doesn't sound like sabotage to me. It sounds like the interests of your boss and senior are not in alignment. Sabotage is on purpose

Comment: @SaggingRufus You need to trust me on this one, I could probably write an entire book about situations like this. I asked a different boss I get along with really well (he is for a nother team) and even he told be to be extra careful with this senior. The space in our company is limited, and if I as a Junior can't keep up the the standards they have for seniors, I will be replaced by a senior sooner or later.

Comment: @Pudora that makes more sense. That may also be worth adding to the question (just so people don't need to look through the comments to find it).

Comment: `this form is extremely long. It takes more than 15 minutes to fill out `  That isn't a long form... trust me.

Answer (score 15):

The point of giving feedback is to let people know where they need to improve - clearly you feel that your senior has room for improvement so by not saying anything you are basically ensuring that he won't be able to do that.

> If I am honest I fear it hurts my future with the company.

If your concern is regarding him knowing that you have "bad things" to say about him and that negatively effecting his judgement about your future at the company - well continually dodging doing the feedback is like waving a giant flashing banner that says "You won't like what I have to say!" and if he doesn't know what those "bad things" are then he might just assume they are worse then the truth. At least giving him the feedback gives you the control over *how* your concerns are communicated and you can frame them constructively.

Also constantly refusing what is seemingly a reasonable request from your senior (given this appears to be an established part of the company culture) isn't exactly doing your future prospects at the company much good!

> It takes more than 15min

Oh. The *horror!*

**EDIT:**

Following the OP's comments that they are concerned regarding this senior potentially sabotaging them.

This being the case I would suggest that this actually strengthens the need to do the feedback. The best defense against colleagues (particularly seniors) who may be out to sabotage you is documented actions. As things stand:

> asked me several times via mail, chat

So the senior has multiple documented instances of him asking for feedback, as per what the company encourages. The OP has some evasive responses to these requests. Looking at the documented evidence at this point it would be very easy for the senior to paint a picture to *their* bosses as being the "team player" and the OP as being uncooperative and recalcitrant. If you're concerned about someone shooting you then don't hand them a loaded gun, which is what dodging their request does here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I really can't give him constructive feedback. I think of him as a bad person. I either have to lie and write only positive things. Or it would be unconstructive bashing. I really don't know how to find anything constructive.

Comment: @Pudora if it's him as a person you don't like then just keep the feedback purely about work (as it should be anyway)

Comment: It could also make it look like you didn't understand the work you reviewed so are scared to fill out the form.

Comment: it is not that I don't like hima s a person, I don't really want to get into detail, but I know for a fact that he tries to sabotage my work to get me out of the company

Comment: @Pudora <sigh /> You must be tired from from shifting all those goalposts. I know I'm tired of chasing them.

Comment: @motosubatsu I am sorry, I don't understand what you mean. English is not my native language.

Comment: I will write one specific example:
Our Boss told me to do something, like "Do this and show your personal skillset like x, y and z!" afterwards he comes up to me as says "No do a b and c, I know you can do x, y and z you don't have to prove it" If I tell him our boss said I should do x, y and z, he tells me "That is not open for discussion I know better what our boss wants from you"

Comment: @Pudora ["Moving the goalposts"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_the_goalposts#Logical_fallacy)  - essentially I can't help if you keep adding new things that change the question. "I don't want to write feedback for my boss" is different from from "I don't want to write feedback for my boss because I think he's a bad person" which in turn is completely different from "I don't want to write feedback to my boss whom I believe is sabotaging me"

Comment: @motosubatsu I am sorry, I wanted to keep it general so it is helpful for others. I didn't think it would change the answer. He is not my boss, he is in a position where he can tell our boss about my progress and helps with the decision progess. But from your written "headlines" it is in my specific case the last one. I added the example also in the question. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: @Pudora I've updated my answer to address the "fear of sabotage" aspect.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think that's a good answer. If would be good if we could assume OP works in a constructive environment, where problems are discussed and people aren't bullied. But many workplaces aren't like that. I've witnessed so many situations where people were bullied based on their constructive, fair input. OP didn't write much about what the "sabotage" looks like, but if he's right that he's been sabotaged than we even have reasons to think it's definitely not a constructive environment. I assume when answering here it's best to accept what OP says as a given, not to put it into quest.

Comment: Sorry @BigMadAndy I'm not quite following you!

Comment: @motosubatsu BigMad is taking your comment of `If you're concerned about someone shooting you then don't hand them a loaded gun` to  the next step - which is if you fill out the form with anything negative, it's just ammo that's going to get shot at you later.  By saying what you suggest, it could easily spell dull pointless work for the rest of the time at that company.

Comment: @UKMonkey - I was suggesting that *refusing to do the form* was the "handing someone the loaded gun"

Comment: @motosubatsu indeed, but saying something negative may be like pulling the trigger.

Comment: @UKMonkey all depends on what and *how* they say it, it's hard to be specific without seeing the sort of thing the form asks but responding with something reasonably neutral, constructive and non-personal - even if it's bland. Is much safer IMHO, if the OP *really* can't think of something to say without either lying through their teeth or pulling that trigger (so to speak) then it's at the point where they should be escalating this to their manager or HR and indicating that they feel the senior may retaliate.

Comment: @motosubatsu HR is not your friend. Escalating it to HR could be the worst thing to do. Taking the matter to the supervisor/manager is definitely a safer option.

Comment: @Sufian while I agree absolutely with "HR is not your friend" it's important to remember that they aren't (always) your enemy either - if the actions of the senior are demonstrably damaging to the **business** then they could be a very useful port of call.

Answer (score 2):

> Also these are completely optional

Regardless of whether you have to write 1 or 40 reviews. It doesn't matter. Optional feedback is exactly that. Optional. If you don't want to do it you don't have to do it. You can say no, or you can make a full on excuse it doesn't matter he can't fire you for not doing *optional* feedback.

If you feel pressured into it speak to your manager. Say you don't want to do it and he's pressuring you for one although it's clearly optional. Assuming the way he's emailing you he expects it as it's the 'norm' so dodging it probably not the best idea in general (doesn't look good on you)

Comment: This doesn't sound optional

Comment: @SaggingRufus OP mentioned "Also these are completly optional". Whether they are or not. OP seems to think they are

Comment: I know they say that, but I can't imagine they would continue to push on something optional. What more likely is once you have been there a while and they trust your judgement, then they are "optional".

Comment: Being able to provide feedback to a colleague through a peer review is an important skill.  A skill based on the behavior of the Senior colleague appears to be desired at the company.  It might not be as optional as the author believes it to be.

Comment: It is completly optional. And it is encouraged to be done in free time. Because if it wasn't optional the company would have to give us the time during our work day to fill out the forms.

Comment: @Pudora There's a difference between optional and optional. Teambuilding events are optional, but skip enough and you'll get reprimanded as you're clearly signaling that you're not a team player. Yours is a similar situation, the reviews are optional, but it still sends a message if you refuse to do them, a message you do not want to send. So yes they are "optional", but not really.

Comment: @kevin thank you for your input! That is an interesting way to look at it. I am actually a person who usually doesn’t go to Christmas party’s or similar events because I am scared of big amounts of people. When I went last Christmas people were pleasantly surprised and told me for days how happy they were I valued them enough to go.